# Server Side Encryption with s3Boto - Server Side Encryption with KMS managed key requires HTTP header x-amz-server-side-encryption : aws:kms

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

I am trying to setup server side encryption on my django app for file uploads. I am using s3Boto3Storage. I can't find clear documentation on how to implement server side encryption, and when trying to upload my file, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: Server Side Encryption with KMS managed key requires HTTP header x-amz-server-side-encryption : aws:kms
```

Here is what my settings look like:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'tickets'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = ''
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_ENCRYPTION = True

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is telling you that you need to include the 'x-amz-server-side-encryption : aws:kms' header somewhere here - possibly in your AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS dict.

If you are trying to use a custom CMK to encrypt, you'll need to structure the additional headers like this:

```
"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms" # This value instructs the request to use a CMK for 
    # server-side encryption, and requires you to pass your custom CMK id to the value
    # for the next param, 'SSEKMSKeyId'.
    # The other acceptable value is AES256, which uses the AWS S3 SSE to encrypt, and not a CMK.
"SSEKMSKeyId": "<your kms cmk key id goes here>" # This is the id of your custom CMK. 
    # This is not required if you set "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256" above.
```

The relevant documentation, which I didn't get at first either:

> **x-amz-server-side-encryption**  The Server-side encryption algorithm
> used when storing this object in S3 (e.g., AES256, aws:kms).  Valid
> Values: AES256 | aws:kms
>
> **x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id**  If the
> x-amz-server-side-encryption is present and has the value of aws:kms,
> this header specifies the ID of the AWS Key Management Service (AWS
> KMS) master encryption key that was used for the object.
>
> If the value of x-amz-server-side-encryption is aws:kms, this header specifies the
> ID of the AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) master encryption key
> that will be used for the object. If you specify
> x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms, but do not provide
> x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id, Amazon S3 uses the
> default AWS KMS key to protect the data.

The S3 PUT documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html